# Width of dynamic created Label in runtime on C#

Tags: c#, .net, runtime, label

I create Label in runtime: `Label myLabel = new Label {Text = "somText"};`. After that `myLabel.Width` equals default value `104`. How I can know real width of `myLabel`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SizeF size = myLabel.CreateGraphics().MeasureString(myLabel.Text, myLabel.Font);
```

Answer (score 2):

The real width is 104. Labels have a property called AutoSize. The width will expand or contract depending on the text you set. You can set the AutoSize property to false and set your own width though.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `myLabel.ActualWidth` ?

Answer (score 1):

Surely the width is the width? Remeber to disbale `Autosize` if you want to fix the width at a certain value.